# estimating effect size with sMAPE in published results

Tags: time-series, forecasting, effect-size, mape

I'm struggling to get the concept of effect size in the published forecasting literature. Most common metric that is used is the [symmetric Mean Absolute Percentage Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error) (sMAPE). For instance see below, a table below published in the M3 competition where the naive model is 16.91. The best model theta has 13.85 and second best model forecastpro has 13.86. (All are highlighted)

My question is:

1. If I had calculate the effect size should I just say that theta
   method has 18.09% (1-13.85/16.91) improvement in forecasting vs.
   naive method and forecast pro had a 18.03% (1-13.86/16.91)
   improvement in forecasting accuracy?

OR

2. Should I say that for Theta considering naive2 as benchmark the improvement in forecasting is 3.06% (16.91%-13.85%) or 3.05% (16.91%-13.86%) for forecast pro?

[image]

Comment: I would say this is an 18.09% improvement, or say it's a 3.06 point improvement. (just to clarify which way I'm talking about.)  For uses like this contest, the % improvement seems more meaningful.

Comment: This might be of interest!!http://autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/the-m3-forecasting-competitions-monthly-calculations-were-off